# Add a new root node to django-mptt tree

Tags: python, django, django-mptt, factory-boy

How can I add a new root node to an existing tree in django-mptt? I am using Django 1.7.4 and django-mptt==0.6.1 with FactoryBoy to test trees.  I tried the following:

```
my_leaf.move_to(my_root, position='left') # creates a new tree
my_leaf.move_to(None, position='this_is_ignored') # also creates a new tree

newroot = factories.MyFactory.build(parent=None, name="NewRoot")
newroot.insert_at(self.my_root, position='left', save=True)
```

Everything I do creates a new tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree has one root node. If you're trying to add a new root node, it means adding a new tree. django-mptt supports either having one tree (just only create one root node), or a whole forest of trees.

You basically never need to use `.move_to()`, unless you're doing something really special like manually-user-ordered nodes. Just set the parent to None. I don't know much about FactoryBoy but the usual way to create a new root node is just:

```
MyNode.objects.create(name='NewRoot', parent=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying to replace the root node with another one.  Lets say I have only unearthed part of the tree:
node B > node C > node D

and later I determine that there is really a node A which is the ancestor for nodes b, c, and d.  How would I put node A into that tree and make it the new root?

Comment: `A = MyNode.objects.create(name='A') ; B.parent = A ; B.save()` would be the standard way to do that.